# How to draw an arenium ion with chemfig?

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

This question is fairly straightforward, I hope. I want to achieve this, including the plus and the incomplete circle.

I can already draw the benzene bit with chemfig, positioning the plus and removing the part of the electron delocalisation circle is what I'm looking for.

It looks like a lot of places draw it by placing an `\oplus` on the carbon at the top, but I can't do that for my output.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{**[60,-240]6(-(-[:90,,,,draw=none]+)---(-[:60]R)(-[:120]H)--)}

\end{document}
```

Have a look at section *Rings* > *Angular Position* for the arc inside the ring and section *Customization of bonds* (for `draw=none`) of `chemfig`'s manual.

[image]

Comment: Nice. If I may suggest: I'd do the diagonal edges shorter (not sure how) and with a wider angle, maybe `(-[:45]R)(-[:135]H)`?

Comment: @Alenanno bonds have five parameters: `<bond>[<angle>,<factor>,<arrival>,<departure>,<tikz code>]`. Those changes are up to you :) They aren't the essential patr of the question.

Comment: Why up to me? It's not my question. :)

Comment: @Alenanno I meant if you ever need to draw this kind of ion in one of your documents you're (of course) free to change the molecule details such as bond lengths :)

Comment: Mine was simply a suggestion for this particular answer. You're free to accept the suggestion or not, but I don't see the relevance of what you're saying.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I found the small little section in chemfig's manual about the start/end angle of the ring, too.